# Self-referential Sudoku

Tags: sudoku, calculation-puzzle

I built this a while back but never had a good forum for it; this seems like the perfect spot to turn it loose.  This is a 'traditional' Sudoku; cells are filled with numbers from 1 through 9, and all usual Sudoku rules apply.
[image: Self-Referential Sudoku]

As far as I know (unless I've made a transcription error) this should be rigorously solvable without any guesswork.  Enjoy!

Comment: This looks brutal o_o I'm impressed!

Comment: @Kevin Thank you!  In retrospect I wish I'd moved a couple of cell-equations out of the central box to balance things better, but overall I'm immensely pleased with how this one came out.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "Di" isn't an element symbol. (..and then I realised you were using grid identifiers, not the periodic table.)

Comment: This looks great, I started it on paper and quickly realized, no, this size paper won't work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I got:

> `342|975|168`
>  `765|821|934`
>  `891|364|527`
>  `---+---+---`
>  `926|538|741`
>  `187|496|352`
>  `534|217|689`
>  `---+---+---`
>  `479|652|813`
>  `253|189|476`
>  `618|743|295`

The steps I took to get there were:

> De can't be one because it is the sum of two numbers.
>  De can't be two because then Fd and Hd would both be one, but they are in the same column.
>  De must be at least 3.
>  De >= 3 and De * Fd <= 9, so Fd <= 3.
>  If Fd = 3, then De = 3, but they are in the same box. So Fd <= 2.
>  If Fd = 1, then Ef = De. But they are in the same box. So Fd = 2.
>
>  ------------------------------------------------
>
>  Ef = De * 2.
>  De = 2 + Hd.
>  Ef = (2+Hd) * 2.
>  Ef = 4 + 2*Hd.
>  If Ef <= 9, Hd <= 2.
>  Hd can't be 2 because Fd is 2. So Hd = 1.
>
>  De = 3.
>  Ef = 6.
>
>  ------------------------------------------------
>
>  Hd is 1, so neither Gf nor Hg may be 1.
>  Gf * Hg <= 9, so they are either (2,2) or (2,3) or (2,4) or (3,3), So Fh is 4 or 6 or 8 or 9.
>  He = 1 = Ee - Fh, so Ee = Fh + 1. So Ee is 5 or 7 or 9 or 10.
>
>  Ee = Cd * Hc.
>  Both Cd and Hc are in line with Hd, so Ee can't be 5 or 7.
>  So Ee = 9 and Fh = 8.
>
>  Gf and Hg are (2,4), but we don't yet know which is which.
>  Dc is 6.
>
>  ------------------------------------------------
>
>  Ee is 9, so Cd and Hc are both 3. (They can't be 1 and 9 because they're both in line with Hd, which is 1)
>  Dd - Gf = 3.
>  Gf is either 2 or 4, so Dd is either 5 or 7.
>  Ha = Ff - Dd, and Ha != 1 because it is in line with Hd.
>  If Dd is 7, then either Ha is 1 or Ff is 9, but both are contradictions. So Dd must be 5.
>
>  Gf = 2.
>  Hg = 4.
>
>  ------------------------------------------------
>  Ha = Ff - Dd = Ff - 5, So Ff > 5.
>  Ff is lin line with 6, 8, and 9, so Ff = 7.
>  Ha = 2.
>
>  ------------------------------------------------
>
>  Da = Bf + Fh = Bf + 8.
>  So Da = 9 and Bf = 1.
>  Fe = 1 because it's the only remaining cell in the center box that could be 1.
>
>  ------------------------------------------------
>  Bi = Fh - Ed = 8 - Ed, so Ed < 8.
>  Ed can only be 8 or 4.
>  So Ed = 4, and Bi = 4.
>
>  De = 4 = Be * Ch. Be can't be 1 or 4.
>  So Be = 2 and Ch = 2.
>
>  ------------------------------------------------
>  Df is 8, because it's the last cell in the center box.
>  If is 3, because it's the only cell in the box that can be 3.
>  Ei = If - Gh = 3 - Gh, so Gh <= 2.
>  Gh is in line with 2, so Gh = 1 and Ei = 2.
>
>  ------------------------------------------------
>  Ig = 2.
>  Db = 2.
>  Ac = 2.
>  Dh = 4.
>  ------------------------------------------------
>  Ba = He - Di, so He > Di.
>  He can be (5,6,7,8). Di can be 1 or 7.
>  If Di is 7, He is 8 and Ba is 1. But Ba can't be 1. So Di = 1.
>  Dg = 7.
>
>  ------------------------------------------------
>  Ih = Bh + Hi, and Hi >= 5, So Bh <= 4.
>  Bh can't be 1,2, or 4, so Bh = 3.
>  Ih <= 9, so Hi is 5 or 6.
>  If Hi is 5, Ih is 8, but Fh is 8. So Hi = 6 and Ih = 9.
>  ------------------------------------------------
>  Fg = 6.
>  Ah = 6.
>  Fi = 9.
>  Eg = 3.
>  Gi = 3.
>  Eh = 5.
>  Hh = 7.
>  ------------------------------------------------
>  Ba = He - 1. He can be 5 or 8, so Ba can be 4 or 7. But Ba can't be 4, so Ba = 7 and He = 5.
>  ------------------------------------------------
>  Ea and Ec can only be (1,7,8). So Id = Ea * Ec is 7 or 8.
>  He is 8, so Id can't be 8, so Id is 7.
>  Ea can't be 7, so Ea is 1 and Ec is 7.
>  Eb = 8.
>  ------------------------------------------------
>  Fc is 4 or 5. Ga is 4, 5, or 6. Bd = Fc + Ga, so Bd can't be 6. So Gd is the only cell in the column that can be 6.
>  Hf = 9.
>  Hb = 5.
>  Bd <= 9, so Ga can't be 6. Hb is 5, so Ga can't be 5. So Ga = 4.
>  Ie = 4.
>  Ge = 5.
>  Ii = 5.
>  Gg = 8.
>  Gb = 7.
>  Gc = 9.
>  Ce = 6.
>  Ae = 7.
>  Ci = 7.
>  Ai = 8.
>  Bd = 8.
>  Bd = Fc + Ga, so 8 = Fc + 4, So Fc = 4.
>  Fa = 5.
>  Fb = 3.
>  Ad = 9.
>  Bc = 5.
>  Ca = 8.
>  Aa = 3.
>  Ia = 6.
>  Ic = 8.
>  Ib = 1.
>  Cc = 1.
>  Ag = 1.
>  Ab = 4.
>  Bb = 6.
>  Cb = 9.
>  Af = 5.
>  Cf = 4.
>  Cg = 5.
>  Bg = 9.

Comment: This tracks pretty close to my own solution - nicely done! I'll give folks another day or so to poke around before accepting...

Comment: Well done! I solved this using the UglyPileOfCode™ method and can confirm that yours is the only correct solution.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage, nice :-) I considered writing some ugly code as well, but I couldn't think of a nice way to get the complexity down. Sudoku solvers tend to take factorial time if you don't approach them right.

Comment: This is the same answer I got. My method is secret :D (less than one second to solve)